# Something is filtering my shortcodes... Can't figure out what

Tags: filters, shortcode

Something seems to be filtering out my shortcodes. I'm not sure what or where, and I've looked just about everywhere trying to find it. Is there anything I can do to find out what filters are being applied before output is generated so I can try and see where the culprit is? I've already read through all the likely code, and disabled all the plugins, but still nothing....

Thanks!

Comment: HI @scott. I think it might help to see your shortcode function and noting where you put it to better understand your issue. Is it in the editor or are you executing it with do_shortcode()? If the latter, where. Finally, have you confirmed that it works on other sites and have you tried it with Twenty Ten enabled?

Answer (score 2):

You can see a list of functions for a specific filter via the `$wp_filter` global.

```
global $wp_filter;
print_r( $wp_filter['Your_filter'] );
```

Print out the complete `$wp_filter` or like the example above, just the specific filter.